# How to map <space> while still pressed plus other key to something in vim

Tags: vim, keymapping

This does not work:

```
imap <Space-;> <leader>
```

This does

```
imap <Space>; <leader>
```

Is there a way to map the keypress down of  only plus other key to something ?

Comment: https://github.com/tomtom/tinykeymap_vim/

Comment: Since `<Space>` is not a modifier key I think you'd have to use another piece of software to handle this.  On OSX you should be able to use [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/).  I'm not sure what you'd use on other platforms.